# terraform oci autonomous database creation ith dataguard enabled

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to create oci autonomous database with dataguard enabled but when we give data guard enabled is true then getting this error
│ Error: 400-InvalidParameter, Operation failed. Cannot enable Autonomous Data Guard during database creation.
so i need to create db with false option for dataguard which will create db and then change data guard option to true to enable data guard for this database.any idea how to call same resource 2 times with false first time and true second time ?

````
resource "oci_database_autonomous_database" "autonomous_database_function" {
  compartment_id         = var.compartment_id
  db_name                = var.db_name
  display_name           = var.db_name
  private_endpoint_label = var.db_name
  admin_password         = random_password.oci_password.result

  is_preview_version_with_service_terms_accepted = "false"
  is_free_tier                                   = "false"
  is_dedicated                                   = "false"
  db_workload                                    = var.db_workload
  cpu_core_count                                 = var.cpu_core_count
  is_auto_scaling_enabled                        = var.auto_scaling_enabled
  is_auto_scaling_for_storage_enabled            = var.auto_scaling_enabled
  is_mtls_connection_required                    = var.is_mtls_connection_required
  data_storage_size_in_tbs                       = var.data_storage_size_in_tbs
  license_model                                  = var.license_model
  nsg_ids                                        = var.nsg_ids
  db_version                                     = var.db_version
  is_data_guard_enabled                          = var.is_data_guard_enabled
  database_edition                               = var.database_edition
  is_local_data_guard_enabled                    = var.local_dg
  # Networking
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id

  dynamic "customer_contacts" {
    for_each = var.alert_recepient_email_address
    content {
      email = customer_contacts.value
    }
  }
  scheduled_operations {
    #Required
    day_of_week {
      #Required
      name = var.sched_ops_day_time[0]
    }
    scheduled_start_time = var.sched_ops_day_time[1]
  }
}```
````

Comment: Well, run it first time, change the value and see what will happen.

Comment: yeah it works but i don't want to run 2 times.. just exploring if we can code to run 2 times with false first run and true second run

Comment: I guess that's something to check with provider maintainers and/or Oracle about the API implementation. But if it was that easy to switch between values in a single run idempotency would be hard to keep.

Comment: Yeah..i agree..